# Write operation cost

Tags: performance, go, io

I have a Go program which writes strings into a file.I have a loop which is iterated **20000 times** and in each iteration i am writing around 20-30 strings into a file. I just wanted to know which is the best way to write it into a file.

- Approach 1: Keep open the file pointer at the start of the code and
  write it for every string. It makes it 20000*30 write operations.
- Approach 2: Use bytes.Buffer Go and store everything in the buffer and
  write it at the end.Also in this case should the file pointer be
  opened from the beginning of the code or at the end of the code. Does
  it matter?

I am assuming approach 2 should work better. Can someone confirm this with a reason. **How does writing at once be better than writing periodically. Because the file pointer will anyways be open.**
I am using `f.WriteString(<string>)` and `buffer.WriteString(<some string>)` buffer is of type `bytes.Buffer` and `f` is the file pointer open.

Answer (score 8):

[bufio](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio) package has been created exactly for this kind of task. Instead of making a syscall for each Write call `bufio.Writer` buffers up to a fixed number of bytes in the internal memory before making a syscall. After a syscall the internal buffer is reused for the next portion of data

Comparing to your second approach `bufio.Writer`

- makes more syscalls (`N/S` instead of `1`)
- uses less memory (`S` bytes instead of `N` bytes)

where `S` - is buffer size (can be specified via `bufio.NewWriterSize`), `N` - total size of data that needs to be written.

Example usage (https://play.golang.org/p/AvBE1d6wpT):

```
f, err := os.Create("file.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer f.Close()

w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, ")
fmt.Fprint(w, "world!")
err = w.Flush() // Don't forget to flush!
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: How does the second approach require fixed amount of memory. Can you please explain that? because the buffer keeps growing according to the requirement.

Comment: yes true thanks for the edit but still writing all the bytes at once would make it faster? Lets say there are 20,000 strings with 1000 characters in each. It is hardly 20 MB.

Comment: You can measure it. But overhead of 5000 syscalls that are needed to write 20Mb with 4kb buffer is less than a millisecond. Also unless you know the final size of data that you need to write before creating bytes,Buffer, it (bytes.Buffer) will likely have to be re-sized and it will certainly slow your app down.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get why does it have to resize and how does it slow down the app? If overhead of 5000 syscalls that are needed to write 20Mb with 4kb buffer is less than a millisecond then no point in digging more into this topic but just wanted to know.

Comment: Imagine you have byte.Buffer that is backed up by 10kb array. When you write 20kb of data to this byte.Buffer it will automaticlly allocate 20kb, copy the existing array to the beginning of the new array (and later will have to garbage collect the old array). As you can imagine none of these operations are free.

Answer (score 4):

The operations that take time when writing in files are the syscalls and the disk I/O. The fact that the file pointer is open doesn't cost you anything. So naively, we could say that the second method is best.

Now, as you may know, you OS doesn't directly write into files, it uses an internal in-memory cache for files that are written and do the real I/O later. I don't know the exacts details of that, and generally speaking I don't need to.

What I would advise is a middle-ground solution: do a buffer for every loop iteration, and write this one N times. That way to cut a big part of the number of syscalls and (potentially) disk writes, but without consuming too much memory with the buffer (dependeing on the size of your strings, that my be a point to be taken into account).

I would suggest benchmarking for the best solution, but due to the caching done by the system, benchmarking disk I/O is a real nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Syscalls are not cheap, so the second approach is better.

You can use [lat_syscall](http://lmbench.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/man?keyword=lat_syscall&section=8) tool from lmbench to measure how long it takes to call single `write`:

```
$ ./lat_syscall write
Simple write: 0.1522 microseconds
```

So, on my system it will take approximately 20000 * 0.15μs = 3ms extra time just to call `write` for every string.