# Improve the speed of fmt.Println

Tags: go

I have a prgram that on certain occasions needs to print 8^20 lines, which takes upward of 30 seconds, I was wondering if it was possible to somehow "buffer" the output to os.Stdout and flush the output at the end of the algorithm. I've tried using os.Pipe as os.Stdout, but that did not increase the speed of the prints.

Is there a way to accomplish that without replacing fmt.Println()?

Comment: I am afraid you will need to change your write methods; I believe the performance issue is because of the syscalls (see _[Write Operation Cost](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34629965/1248449)_).

Comment: You could try: https://play.golang.org/p/Xnkanapx1-

Comment: You need to replace `fmt.Println`. That way you can buffer the writes and replace all the reflection calls. Writing to a terminal can also be very slow if stdout is connected to a tty.

Comment: How about storing lines in slice or whatever and then fmt.Println it out in one shot instead of invoking for every line.

Comment: The buffer implementation in Go is in the pkg "bufio", so my answer is the same of Martin Gallagher  https://play.golang.org/p/Xnkanapx1-

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to "compile" the format strings which supposedly never change. For example, see  https://github.com/larytet/binlog