# Achieving high throughput with Go TCP client-server

Tags: linux, go, tcp

I'm going to develop a simple TCP client and server and I want to achieve high throughput (300000 Requests/Second) which is easy to reach with Cpp or C TCP client and server on a server hardware. I mean a server with 48 Cores and 64G Memory.

On my testbed, both client and server have 10G network interface card and I have receive-side-scaling at server side and transmit-packet-steering enabled at the client.

I configure the client to send 10 thousand requests per second. I just run multiple instances of Go `go run client.go` from a bash script to increase the throughput. However, in this way, Go is going to create lots of threads at the operating systems and a large number of threads results in high context switching cost, and I could not approach such throughputs. I suspected the number of Go instances I'm running from the command line. The code below is the code snippet for the client in the approach:

```
func Main(cmd_rate_int int, cmd_port string) {

   //runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2) // set maximum number of processes to be used by this applications

   //var rate float64 = float64(rate_int)

   rate := float64(cmd_rate_int)

   port = cmd_port

   conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", port)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("ERROR", err)
       os.Exit(1)
   }

   var my_random_number float64 = nextTime(rate) * 1000000
   var my_random_int int = int(my_random_number)
   var int_message int64 = time.Now().UnixNano()
   byte_message := make([]byte, 8)

   go func(conn net.Conn) {
       buf := make([]byte, 8)

       for true {
           _, err = io.ReadFull(conn, buf)
           now := time.Now().UnixNano()

           if err != nil {
               return
           }

           last := int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(buf))
           fmt.Println((now - last) / 1000)
       }
       return

   }(conn)

   for true {
       my_random_number = nextTime(rate) * 1000000
       my_random_int = int(my_random_number)
       time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(my_random_int))
       int_message = time.Now().UnixNano()
       binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(byte_message, uint64(int_message))
       conn.Write(byte_message)
   }
}
```

So I try to run all my Go threads by calling `go client()` in the `main` so I do not run multiple instances in the Linux command line. I thought it may be a better idea. And it is really a better idea basically and the number of threads doesn't increase toward 700 or so in the operating system. But the throughput still is low and it seems it doesn't employ all capability of the underlying hardware. Actually, you may want to see the code I have run in the second approach:

```
func main() {

   //runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2) // set maximum number of processes to be used by this applications
   args := os.Args[1:]
   rate_int, _ := strconv.Atoi(args[0])
   client_size, _ := strconv.Atoi(args[1])
   port := args[2]

   i := 0
   for i <= client_size {
       go client.Main(rate_int, port)
       i = i + 1
   }

   for true {

   }
}
```

I was wondering what is the best practice for in order to reach high throughput? I have always heard that Go is lightweight and performant and pretty comparable with C/Cpp pthread. However, I think in terms of performance still C/Cpp is far far better than Go. I might do something really wrong on this issue, so I would be happy if anybody can help to achieve high throughput with Go.

Comment: please post a full reproducible example so we can talk about your attempts. As of now it is hardly possible to make sense of it.

Comment: https://github.com/sarsanaee/GoWorkloadGenerator, There are two branches there that are related to both approaches I described here! Thanks :) @mh-cbon

Comment: thanks, the code you have posted seems able to send 300k/qps, at one detail, the call to fmt.* kills its performance. That is easy to find using profiling (https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs), and this is well-known (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104727/improve-the-speed-of-fmt-println). I m also adding a slight rewrite below for sharing purposes, in no case this is close to production ready.

Comment: one thing to note about your sleep and the duration computation system remains totally obscure to me, it did not return anything relevant during my tests.

Comment: You are only reading 8 bytes at a time with an unbuffered connection -- it's a TCP stream, there's no reason to not buffer that. There is also an empty `for` loop in your code, which is always a programming error. It's consuming 100% of a CPU core for no reason, and blocking the scheduler.

Comment: io.ReadFull() syscall is a blocking one, so it is not EMPTY for loop that consumes entire CPU utilization. I don't think there is any problem with it! @JimB

Comment: @SeyedAlirezaSanaeeKohroudi: the last line of your `main` function is simply `for true {}`. `ReadFull` is blocking, but it's translating to a syscall every time because of the small read size, where as a buffered reader would be much more efficient.

Comment: Ohh yes! That one really hurts the performance, however, I monitored the CPU utilization but interestingly the utilization was low!!!! WHY?! @JimB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a quick rework of the op code.
As the original source code is working, it does not provide a solution, however it illustrates bucket token usage, and few other small go tips.

It does re use similar default values as op source code.

It demonstrates you do not need two files / programs, to provide both client and server.

It demonstrates usage of flag package.

It shows how to parse unix nano timestamp appropriately using time.Unix(x,y)

It shows how to take advantage of io.Copy to write-what-you-read on the same net.Conn. Rather than manual writing.

Still, this is improper for production delivery.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "net"
    "os"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"

    "github.com/juju/ratelimit"
)

var total_rcv int64

func main() {

    var cmd_rate_int float64
    var cmd_port string
    var client_size int

    flag.Float64Var(&cmd_rate_int, "rate", 400000, "change rate of message reading")
    flag.StringVar(&cmd_port, "port", ":9090", "port to listen")
    flag.IntVar(&client_size, "size", 20, "number of clients")

    flag.Parse()

    t := flag.Arg(0)

    if t == "server" {
        server(cmd_port)

    } else if t == "client" {
        for i := 0; i < client_size; i++ {
            go client(cmd_rate_int, cmd_port)
        }
        // <-make(chan bool) // infinite wait.
        <-time.After(time.Second * 2)
        fmt.Println("total exchanged", total_rcv)

    } else if t == "client_ratelimit" {
        bucket := ratelimit.NewBucketWithQuantum(time.Second, int64(cmd_rate_int), int64(cmd_rate_int))
        for i := 0; i < client_size; i++ {
            go clientRateLimite(bucket, cmd_port)
        }
        // <-make(chan bool) // infinite wait.
        <-time.After(time.Second * 3)
        fmt.Println("total exchanged", total_rcv)
    }
}

func server(cmd_port string) {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", cmd_port)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        go io.Copy(conn, conn)
    }
}

func client(cmd_rate_int float64, cmd_port string) {

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", cmd_port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ERROR", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    go func(conn net.Conn) {
        buf := make([]byte, 8)
        for {
            _, err := io.ReadFull(conn, buf)
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
            // int_message := int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(buf))
            // t2 := time.Unix(0, int_message)
            // fmt.Println("ROUDNTRIP", time.Now().Sub(t2))
            atomic.AddInt64(&total_rcv, 1)
        }
        return
    }(conn)

    byte_message := make([]byte, 8)
    for {
        wait := time.Microsecond * time.Duration(nextTime(cmd_rate_int))
        if wait > 0 {
            time.Sleep(wait)
            fmt.Println("WAIT", wait)
        }
        int_message := time.Now().UnixNano()
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(byte_message, uint64(int_message))
        _, err := conn.Write(byte_message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("ERROR", err)
            return
        }
    }
}

func clientRateLimite(bucket *ratelimit.Bucket, cmd_port string) {

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", cmd_port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ERROR", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    go func(conn net.Conn) {
        buf := make([]byte, 8)
        for {
            _, err := io.ReadFull(conn, buf)
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
            // int_message := int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(buf))
            // t2 := time.Unix(0, int_message)
            // fmt.Println("ROUDNTRIP", time.Now().Sub(t2))
            atomic.AddInt64(&total_rcv, 1)
        }
        return
    }(conn)

    byte_message := make([]byte, 8)
    for {
        bucket.Wait(1)
        int_message := time.Now().UnixNano()
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(byte_message, uint64(int_message))
        _, err := conn.Write(byte_message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("ERROR", err)
            return
        }
    }
}

func nextTime(rate float64) float64 {
    return -1 * math.Log(1.0-rand.Float64()) / rate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** This is a pretty bad answer. Check mh-cbon comments for the reasons.

---

I don't fully understand how you're trying to do so, but if I want to control the rate on Go, I usually do 2 nested for loops:

```
for ;; time.Sleep(time.Second) {
  go func (){
    for i:=0; i<rate; i++ {
      go func (){
        // Do whatever
      }()
    }
  }()
}
```

I'm starting a goroutine inside each loop to:

- on the outer loop, to ensure it's only 1 second between iterations
- on the inner loop, to ensure I can start all the requests I want

Putting this on a problem like yours, it would look something like:

```
package main

import (
        "net"
        "os"
        "time"
)

const (
        rate    = 100000
        address = "localhost:8090"
)

func main() {
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
        if err != nil {
                os.Stderr.Write([]byte(err.Error() + "\n"))
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        for ; err == nil; time.Sleep(time.Second) {
                go func() {
                        for i := 0; i < rate; i++ {
                                go func(conn net.Conn) {
                                        if _, err := conn.Write([]byte("01234567")); err != nil {
                                                os.Stderr.Write([]byte("\nConnection closed: " + err.Error() + "\n"))
                                        }
                                }(conn)
                        }
                }()
        }
}
```

To verify that this is actually sending the target request rate, you can have a test TCP listener like this:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net"
        "os"
        "time"
)

const (
        address = ":8090"
        payloadSize = 8
)
func main() {
        count := 0
        b := make([]byte, payloadSize)
        l, err := net.Listen("tcp", address)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "\nCan't listen to address %v: %v\n", address, err)
                return
        }


   defer l.Close()
    go func() {
            for ; ; time.Sleep(time.Second) {
                    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "\rRate: %v/s       ", count)
                    count = 0
            }
    }()
    for {
            conn, err := l.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "\nFailed to accept connection: %v\n", err)
            }
            for {
                    _, err := conn.Read(b)
                    if err != nil {
                            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "\nConnection closed: %v\n", err)
                            break
                    }
                    count = count + 1
            }
    }
```

}

I found some issues due to not being able to write concurrently into the connection with an error `inconsistent fdMutex`. This is due to reaching over `0xfffff` concurrent writes, which fdMutex does not support. To mitigate this issue, make sure you don't go over that number of concurrent writes. In my system, it was >100k/s. This is not the 300k/s you're expecting, but my system is not prepared for that.

Comment: i don t quiet understand why you d start go routines on every second, that will add lots of works on gc, and probably other things. Also, having one routine for each write does not seem a good way imho, you should block if the conn can t be written anymore. In current code you are accumulating routines at runtime, making this code harzadous.

Comment: Indeed, the danger of accumulating write routines is clear, and that is the error I was having. Including a blocker for concurrent writes includes making the code too complex to write it here, but I usually use a `sync.Mutex` with the number of available resources and substract one while I'm using that resource, adding one once the resource is no longer needed. Regarding the go routine for every second, is to ensure that it takes exactly one second. Since I don't know how long will the loop take, I send it to a goroutine, and then wait an actual 1 second.

Comment: I could use a `time.Ticker` to count the seconds, but again, it would make the code more complex. AFAIK, launching a ton of goroutines, as long as you don't need to copy data into the routine itself (notice that I don't pass any param into the functions), and as long as you're careful to not access anything not concurrency-protected, it does not take that many resources, and simplifies the code.

Comment: take care in `for err==nil` it is referencing a shadowed and concurrently written variable. Also, it is not certain to me that writing the same tcp conn concurrently really adds up speed, I suspect somewhere down line something is synchronizing things, so at best it might filling the underlying buffer faster, not sure. https://golang.org/src/net/net.go#L184. I would not use time.Ticker, i d have to deal with the case where a write > 1s. I d rather use a token bucket https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/RateLimiting.

Comment: Damn, the error. True! I didn't think about that. I didn't know about the bucket wiki page, but I'm surprised about the ticker limit to tens of ops per second. With the simple `for ;;time.Sleep(time.Second){go func (){}()}` I've managed to control the rate precisely up to hundreds of thousands of ops per second, although using libraries that control concurrency on the background...